# How can I write an interface where a class returns the same type as itself?

Tags: typescript, oop, design-patterns

Consider this code, it's written in Typescript but the language I don't think really matters.

```
interface IXY {
  x: number;
  y: number;

  scale(n: number): IXY;
}

interface IXYZ extends IXY {
  z: number;

  scale(n: number): IXYZ;
}

// this is not my real code, just an example.
function flip<T extends IXY>(v: T, flip: boolean): T {
  if (flip) return v.scale(-1); // Error here
  else return v;
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Type 'IXY' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'IXY' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T',
but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'IXY'
```

Now, I understand why this error is occuring. It's because any interface that extends IXY only has to ensure that scale returns something that extends IXY. Consider this example, where `IABC` just returns an `IXY`.

```
interface IABC extends IXY {
  scale(n: number): IXY; // does not have to return IABC.
}
```

I guess my question is, how can I write `IXY`'s .scale to make sure whatever is extending it is returning the same type as that extension? When I call flip with an `IXYZ` I want to know that what I get out is also going to be an `IXYZ`.

How do I write an interface that ensures inheritors return the same type as themselves? How do I make sure I don't lose the `z` in `IXYZ`?

Many thanks.

EDIT:

As some have suggested I can return `this` from the interface, but when I go to implement IXY I get an error.

```
interface IXY {
  x: number;
  y: number;

  scale(n: number): this;
}

interface IXYZ extends IXY {
  z: number;

  scale(n: number): this;
}

class XY implements IXY {
  x: number;
  y: number;

  constructor(x: number, y: number) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  scale(n: number): this { // this won't compile
     return new XY(this.x * n, this.y * n);
  }

  scale(n: number): XY { // neither will this
     return new XY(this.x * n, this.y * n);
  }
}

// this is not my real code, just an example.
function flip<T extends IXY>(v: T, flip: boolean): T {
  if (flip) return v.scale(-1);
  else return v;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you define `scale` like this: `scale(n: number): this;`?

Comment: @Behemoth, when I do that I get a similar error when I go to implement scale in a class. `Type 'XYZ' is not assignable to type 'this'.
  'XYZ' is assignable to the constraint of type 'this', but 'this' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'XYZ'`

Comment: @BenMcLean981 please [edit] the question with whatever code needs to compile in order for you to accept an answer.  If you run into problems with code not in the question, it's hard for others to help.  If you need to implement classes, please show those implementations.

Comment: Note that the `this` type is hard or impossible to produce safely.  Inside `class Foo`, if you return `new Foo()`, this isn't necessarily `this`.  Because `class Bar extends Foo` that doesn't override `scale()` now produces `Foo` instead of `Bar`, oops.  I can demonstrate further if you post relevant example code

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to get so complicated. All you have to do is define the return type of `scale` as [`this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types).

```
interface IXY {
  x: number;
  y: number;

  scale(n: number): this;
}

interface IXYZ extends IXY {
  z: number;

  scale(n: number): this;
}
```

This way you won't get any problems when calling `scale()` since the type of `v` extends `IXY` and also every type that `scale()` can possibly return extends `T`.

```
function flip<T extends IXY>(v: T, flip: boolean): T {
  if (flip) return v.scale(-1); // --> (method) IXY.scale(n: number): T
  else return v;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know `this` was a thing that could be used like this, so thank you. However, when I go to implement `class XY extends IXY`, I get an error on the scale method. The only way I can get it to work is if I `return this`, but I don't want my methods to mutate, I want them to return new objects.

Comment: TIL about the `this` type.

Comment: @Behemoth, sorry I made a typo. When I go to implement the class I get an error. I can modify this by doing `this.x *= n; this.y *=n; return this;`, but I don't want to have to mutate `this`, I want to return a modified copy.

Comment: This sure seems like the right answer to me, but apparently OP has further requirements.  Hopefully the question will either be edited with these requirements, or this answer will be accepted and OP will create a new question to follow up on the class implementation issues